# Remove CLOSELY Matching strings C#

Tags: c#

I have a message composed of closely matching strings . I want to remove closely matching strings from message . By close i mean like if two strings match upto **80%** of their total length , then one of them should be considered duplicate and removed.

The distinct() method from `System.Linq;` or similar stratedgy wont work like I have implemented below because even of one non matching character.

```
string[] masg = {"Hello World","Hello World One","Hello-World","How are you","How are u"};

var distinctStr = masg.Distinct();
masg="";

foreach(string str in distinctStr)
    masg+=str+"~";
```

**Desired Output**

> Hello World~How are you

How to do it . Please provide me ideas or further concepts that I should go through . thanks.

Comment: Without some of your code to start from, the best we can probably do is provide some [reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Comment: Thanks Evil Penguin LCS o is the way to go.  thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do first is define a distance between to strings, for example using the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). After that, you just need to go through the strings, adding them to a set as long as the set does not contain another string with a distance lower than what you desire.

Comment: Thanks , going through LCS , Levenshtein distance.